# How to keep data stored in generic List available during all processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to keep data stored in generic List available during all processes at the same page. please.
I need to Save selected items in generic List . and keep it until selecting all items needed. Then by pressing the second button "show search results" .
 My problem was when I press the second pagination page number, I lose the selected items in previous page "the List is reset".
 Could anyone help me please to keep these selected items accumulated to the List until I finish all items I need to select from all available pages.
[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFFlq.png)
[my linq datacontext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPxp1.png)
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

```
namespace myGoogleLike_webapp
{
    public partial class myForm_EE : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        salesDataContext db = new salesDataContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void search_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        private void BindData()
        {
            string myString = mySearch_TextBox.Text.Trim();

            var myProducts = (from mySection in db.Products
                              where mySection.Name.Contains(myString) 
                              select mySection).ToList();

            if ((myProducts != null) && (myProducts.Count() > 0))
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = myProducts;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had use public List<string> lstSelectedSections = new List<string>();

Comment: then I add ProductId to the List<string> on the checkbox_CheckedChanged event.

Comment: but when I go to next page in the gridview, I lose my first page checked items from my List<string>... ?

Comment: This is a webforms app? And by "processes" you mean you want all current users to be able to see the same list? If so, have you tried placing the list in application state?

Comment: No, actually I want the same user only to see the result, and not all users. " have you tried placing the list in application state?" what do you mean by application state? Excuse me I'm newbie to C#.

Comment: Oh, if you want to store it for a single user, you should store it in session state or view state - the former persists across different pages; the latter is for a single page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx should explain the different types of state in ASP.NET and how to use them.

Comment: thank u  ekolis , I had use ViewState and it works with me perfect.

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer that explains in more detail what I said in the comments - that way you can accept the answer and folks in your situation can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several kinds of state in ASP.NET where you can store data across postbacks:

- Application state: Stores data that is relevant for all users, for instance a cached list of data that is frequently accessed by users.
- Session state: Stores data that is relevant to a particular user's session, for instance an authentication token.
- View state: Stores data that is relevant to a particular page for a particular user, for instance a selected item in a list.
- Control state: Similar to view state, but used for a specific custom/user control, rather than an entire page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx explains in detail the different types of state in ASP.NET and how to use them.